# Rotate quaternion along axis

Tags: javascript, webgl

I got a object in a WebGL context that is rotated by a quaternion. Now I would like to rotate it around the x axis according to the current mouse position. How can I do this? I'm using the glMatrix library.

Comment: Why use a quaterion? A matrix would be far simpler, especially in this scenario (and probably less CPU too).

Comment: How do you figure? A quaternion rotation around the X axis takes a 8 multiplies, 2 additions, and 2 subtractions. The same operation on a 4x4 matrix is 16 multiplies and 8 additions. The quaternion math will always be faster, and the only reason to go with matrix math from the get go is if you're going to be forced to convert to a matrix down the line anyway (ie: to pass into a shader)

Answer (score 2):

glMatrix doesn't (currently) include much in the way of quaternion transforms. Sorry. Probably not a bad idea to add, however.

You can poke around online to find some references for these things. For example: [this page](http://content.gpwiki.org/index.php/OpenGL%3aTutorials%3aUsing_Quaternions_to_represent_rotation) has some good examples for basic quaternion math. In the meantime, if all your looking for is rotation around X I *think* this will do the trick: (Note! Untested code ahead! This is just a quick optimization of the algorithms on the page I linked)

```
/**
 * Rotates a quaternion by the given angle around the X axis
 *
 * @param {quat4} quat quat4 to rotate
 * @param {number} angle Angle (in radians) to rotate
 * @param {quat4} [dest] quat4 receiving operation result. If not specified result is written to quat
 *
 * @returns {quat4} dest if specified, quat otherwise
 */
quat4.rotateX = function (quat, angle, dest) {
    if (!dest) { dest = quat; }

    // NOTE: I really have no idea what this is for, the guy on the linked page seemed to think it was necessary, though. 
    angle *= 0.5; 

    var qax = quat[0], qay = quat[1], qaz = quat[2], qaw = quat[3],
        qbx = Math.sin(angle), qbw = Math.cos(angle);

    dest[0] = qax * qbw + qaw * qbx;
    dest[1] = qay * qbw + qaz * qbx;
    dest[2] = qaz * qbw - qay * qbx;
    dest[3] = qaw * qbw - qax * qbx;
};
```

In the meantime, feel free to add an issue to the [gl-matrix github page](https://github.com/toji/gl-matrix) to request any operations you think would be helpful.

Comment: Thanks for this answer and the link! glMatrix's quat4 has a multiplication function to make this easier, as in the answer I've now added.

Comment: Oh, and dividing the angle by two is needed because a quaternian for a rotation around an axis is in terms of cos and sin of half the angle of rotation, as mentioned near the beginning of the page you linked.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
quat4.rotateX = function (quat, angle, dest) {
  if (!dest) dest = quat;
  quat4.multiply(quat, [Math.sin(angle/2), 0, 0, Math.cos(angle/2)]);
}
```

which you can use with, e.g.,

```
quat4.rotateX(myQuaternian, Math.PI/4);
```

(Rotation around Y and Z axes can be done by moving that `sin` term to the 2nd or 3rd slot.)